# ClassNotFoundException when trying to connect with mysql dbms?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, classpath

I have seen many solutions in this site relating the same problem that I am facing now, I rectified my project structure also but still no success,

**First** attempt I placed mysqlconnector.jar in **WEB-INF/lib** -> GOT ERROR. 
**Second**, I removed it from lib folder, and added as external jar in build path -> GOT ERROR. 
Also I tried both above ways after placing mysqlconnector jar file in **jre8/lib/ext**  -> NO SUCCESS!

Please ignore any small or irrelevant modifications, I just needed to check the connectivity thats all. I have JRE8 and Tomcat8 server running, which I believe is not an issue in this.

Here is a simple code of connectivity I just want to check if it is establishing a connection or not, that is why I haven't coded any further.

```
public class MySQLConnection {

    public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payinguest";
    public static final String USER = "root";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "root";


    public MySQLConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

My index.jsp is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="com.pg.dao.MySQLConnection"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% MySQLConnection db = new MySQLConnection();%>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.pg.dao.JDBCMySQLConnection.<init>(JDBCMySQLConnection.java:15)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:71)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Correction

```
 Use Jar file Instead of Zip in your class path.
```

Comment: I just want to load/register the driver, rest i can connect it to database and further. My concern is it stops at line Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS); which is simple statement.

Comment: i tried the steps you suggested, but still NO SUCCESS!

Comment: As you have mentioned earlier that you have placed jar file in lib, can you please add that jar file to build path as well and see if it works. Do this Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add JARS and clean the project.

Comment: What about mysqlconnector version compatibility with jdk you are using!!

Comment: Right Click on "My Computer"
    Click on Properties
    Go to Advanced System Settings (On your left hand panel)
    Click on the Advanced Tab and then the "Environment Variables"
    In the System variables, click on New and add "CLASSPATH" as the name and "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java.jar" as the value

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 the latest one. and jdk8

Comment: It should be simple to connect, try above comment to set classpath.

Comment: i have included the connector in jre8/lib/ext/ folder, i think its same as adding CLASSPATH.

Comment: Try clean your project and run again!! Tab Project<Clean!!

Comment: its zip file, do i need jar file??

Comment: Yes, Why would you use zip file? It's obviously jar file.

Comment: my bad, i was careless. Thanxx for discussion.

Comment: I corrected the answer,pls mark if it worked for you.

Comment: yeah, now the jar is all over in jre8/lib/ext and in WEB-INF/lib and also in build path..not added it to CLASSPATH variable although.

Comment: Nice!! It happens.Knew there was something simple missing. Matter of fact you have tried it all.